# How to switch between different CDFs in CDF Player?

Tags: front-end, cdf-format, mac-os-x

I recently got a Mac. It has CDF Player, but not *Mathematica*. How do I get CDF Player to switch between different CDFs on OS X Lion?

### Edit

I forgot to mention that I want to know how to switch between CDFs when in Full Screen mode. There must be a hot key for that. For that matter.... What's the best way to switch from Full Screen to a window with menus?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're talking about, Ted.  On my Mac CDF Player has the standard File menu allowing me to open and close multiple CDFs as usual. I'm on 10.6, which is SnowLeopard, not Lion I guess. Surely, Lion couldn't have dropped the File menu, though? Can you explain more clearly what's going on?

Comment: @ Mark McClure  See my edit above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both, Mathematica and CDF player, full screen or not, to switch between different open files use:

**Windows:** CTRL + F6

**Mac:** Command (or Apple Key) + tilde (or backtick)